# Line break in HTML for Android TextView

Tags: java, android, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a line break in an Android TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview)

I'm trying to express a number with a superscript and other text in three different lines but the line break doesn't work for some reason.

```
TextView tvAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_answer);
tvAnswer.setText(Html.fromHtml("16<sup>4</sup>" + "istext \nistextonanotherline"));
```

The " \n" doesn't cause a line break but it does without the "Html.fromHtml" which I need.

This also doesn't work:

```
tvAnswer.setText(Html.fromHtml("16<sup>4</sup>" + "istext<br>istextonanotherline"));
```

since Android apparently doesn't support the br HTML tag. Help?

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really sure if there's a better way to do the break than "CDATA".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is

```
tvAnswer.setText(Html.fromHtml("16<sup>4</sup>" + "istext "));
    tvAnswer.append("\n");
```