# setText() into a textview from a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android App Development. I am try to view my database using a Textview in my activity.

Here is my setText() java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewlogs); 
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSqlinfo);
LogsDB info = new LogsDB(this);
info.open();
ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
info.close();
tv.setText(data);
}
```

I seem to be getting and error at tv.setText(data);. Stating "The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)" Then when i do the recommended fix it changes

```
tv.setText(data)
```

to

```
tv.setText((CharSequence) data);
```

Then when I test the application I get an error stating that it cannot be cast.
What do I need to change to be able to view my database in the textview?

Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You could use data.toArray().toString()

Comment: `tv.setText(data)` is not applicable for array of string? and you cant cast the list to CharSequence object? you can passed some of strings in the data list `tv.setText(data.get(0))` 0 is index of the list

Comment: Tired that but now where the database values should be it say "Ljava.lang.Object@415b0b38"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple you can use

```
tv.setText(data.toString());
```

instead of

```
tv.setText(data);
```

It will show something like this:
([field1],[field2],...)

Comment: I got that to work is there any way when I add a second entry to my database it appears under the first entry.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more detailed? I didn't understand your question.

Comment: You need to append with a line break. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview)

Comment: Perfect it worked. Thank you both Marco Altran and codeMagic.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take each `String` out of the `ArrayList` and add them to a single `String` object then add that to your `TextView`. Something like

```
String text = "These are my database Strings ";
for (int i=0; i<data.size(), i++)
{
    text = text.concat(data.get(i));  // might want to add a space, ",", or some other separator
}
tv.setText(text);
```

and you can separate the `String`s however you want them to be displayed.