# Have Android respecting line break in text

Tags: java, android, xml, oop, formatting

I have a text to display as TextView in Android, the text consists of various lines like this:

> Text1
>
> Text2
>
> Text3

But the problem is that when displayed it appears like this ignoring the line breaks:

> Text1
> Text2
> Text3

I know what you are thinking, just add `\r\n` at the end of every line, but this isn't an option at the moment for me.

Is there a way to have Android respecting the line breaks in the text?

Thanks! Jose

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a line break in an Android TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview)

Comment: That question has been answered with "\r\n". I specify that in my case that's not a valid solution.

Comment: Is text allways of same length?

Comment: No, it's a long text in lots of different languages, different length's for every language + the text will probably change in time. My @strings are maintained by a third party.

Comment: Line breaks "\n" should work fine May be use the single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: Example obj.setText("Text 1 \n Text 2 \n Text 3 \n");

Answer (score -2):

You're going to need to use `\r\n`, sorry.

Notepad++ can find and replace linebreak charaters with `\r\n`. Not sure if You'd be able to do it programatically