# How to display properly formatted E-mail in TextView in android

Tags: android, email, textview

I am working on an E-mail Application where I have to send and receive and also have to display email in `TextView` when ever user wants to read it

This is the feed I am getting from API :-

```
 {
    "messages":   
    [{"id":"136902",
"from":"Akash",
"email":"akash@email.com",
"subject":"mail App!!",
"message":"Hi Devraj,\n\n \n\nKindly provide sabmail apk for google  play store.\n\n \n\nRegards,\n\nAkash",
"date":"1448870780",
"userid":"75",
"recipients":"devraj@mail.com ",
"status":"0",
"isread":"1",
"priority":"3",
"size":"3057"}
]}
```

I am taking the "message" tag and displaying it in `TextView`. It looks like this

> ***Hi Devraj,Kindly provide mail apk for google  play store.Regards,Akash,***

But, I want it to be look like this,

> Hi Devraj,
>
> Kindly provide mail apk for google  play store.
>
> Regards,
>
> Akash,

How can I do achieve this.

This is the way I am setting it in `TextView`

```
String msg = messageDisc.getMessage();

Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(msg);

emailText.setText(sp);
emailText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Your `message` tag doesn't really look like Html from the feed you posted., or am I wrong..?

Comment: Try one of the solutions suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace: `\n` with `<br>`.

```
String msg = messageDisc.getMessage();
msg = msg.replace("\n", "<br>");
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(msg);
```

Comment: hello AnswerDroid, Thanks for your response.  please let me know what is this ..... msg = msg.replace("\n", "
")    do u want me to hit enter Key for this or just spacebar?

Comment: msg = msg.replace("\n", "<br>"); just type this since <br> will give that space

Comment: @Aspicas  yes.. it did work like charm.. :D. just give me 2 minutes as it takes minimum 2 minutes to accept any answer.. :P

Answer (score 1):

Supply `android:maxLines="<any number>"` to the `TextView`. So that `\n` will work.

Answer (score -1):

first parse the json data and stored it into a different `String`.

Then set the `String` object to the `edittext` by seperating it with a `\n` line.

eg: `emailText.setText(sp+"" +\n+""+obj);`