# I want to write in a different line in textview

Tags: android, textview, line

My point is i only can write/select 1st line of the textview i want to have for example:

My name is:

12345

Is it even possible to write in 2nd line or more lines?

Comment: Have you ever used Html class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a line break in an Android TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382490/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-an-android-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is:\n12345

for more lines use more \n\n\n\n\n :-)

Comment: Thx you saved my day :p

Comment: Thx i use the other / ahaha

Answer (score 0):

You can also do many thing like....Bold italic or showing in list using one Text view.

Write your text in HTML format. i.e

```
String youttext="<b>My Name is Avi</b><br><br> <i>I m a Android Developer</i><br><br><ul><li>I m a Blogger too</li></ul>"

Textview yourview=(Textview) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        yourview.setText(Html.fromHtml(youttext));
```

You can show the Text in HTML format too. If you want to change the specific color text and style or shading etc.